# Alternate way to organize functions in a NSViewController subclass?

Tags: swift, nsviewcontroller

(Swift, OSX)

I currently have a view controller (named ViewController) that manages the view of my application with storyboards, consisting of a couple of text boxes for user input. If the user enters something incorrect, it calls a function that alerts the user to their error (with a `NSAlert` modal), and offers them an option: reset their input, reset their input and previous output, or just dismiss the window.

Problem is, that alert code alone is about 60 lines of code (with functions to display appropriate messages), and I want to move it into another class -- a subclass of `ViewController`, entitled `ErrorResponse`, so it can still access the user interface to appropriately reset their input (i.e., clear an input string field), and do the other tasks mentioned above while avoiding a massive wall of functions in the `ViewController`

I've tried creating a subclass of `ViewController` so the user interface properties are inherited and I can simply access them, however Xcode wants the subclass to implement an init method with NSCoder. (To my knowledge, this is how Xcode sets up a storyboard or .xib to communicate with the controller, as part of the NSViewController class, but this is unrelated to my implmenetation). When I attempt to pass `nil` or a default initialized `NSCoder()` object, I get obscure crashes.

So, is there any way to organize these functions? Or should I just keep them all in the ViewController?

Edit: I also have an existing class called `ErrorCheck` that performs the check to see if there are any errors. Within the ViewContoller, when the input is entered, there is a `guard` statement with a method from ErrorCheck, and if the input is invalid in some way, the corresponding methods in `ErrorResponse` are called.

Code snippet:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    // Input and output text fields
    @IBOutlet weak var inputStr: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputStr: NSTextField!

    // Input and output conversion selection
    @IBOutlet weak var inputSegments: NSSegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputSegments: NSSegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func outputIsSelected(sender: NSSegmentedControl) {

        // Passing all UI elements in (not shown)
        // Not ideal, want to be global obj (see below code)
        guard ErrorCheck().stringIsNotEmpty(inputStr.stringValue) else {
            ErrorResponse().invalidEmptyInput()
            return
        }

        // 0 = DNA, 1 = mRNA, 2 = English
        if (inputSegments.selectedSegment == 0) {
            checkPossibleConversionAndConvertDNA()
        } else if (inputSegments.selectedSegment == 1) {
            checkPossibleConversionAndConvertmRNA()
        } else if (inputSegments.selectedSegment == 2) {
            checkPossibleConversionAndConvertEnglish()
        }

    }
}
```

If I don't subclass ViewController, there is another issue: I can't globally define an object for ErrorResponse, as I can't pass the UI values within the same scope as they are being initialized, so currently I have initialized an ErrorCheck object in each corresponding function... and its messy.

Comment: As you don't post your code, I can't give a specific answer. But I guess you can put your alert code into  a new class subclass to NSAlert, and communicate with ViewController using protocol.

Comment: @luiyezheng Updated w/ code example

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just moving the methods into ViewController. Not the prettiest, but it's functional.